# How to create a mesh on a globe from GeoJSON data?

Tags: three.js, geojson

I am trying to follow Marcs answer from here:
[How can I draw geoJSON in three.js as a mesh and not a line, and fill with color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520463/how-can-i-draw-geojson-in-three-js-as-a-mesh-and-not-a-line-and-fill-with-color).

I need to create a mesh from GeoJSON, But I can not manage to create the faces correctly

I am using `threeGeoJSON.js` from here:
https://github.com/jdomingu/ThreeGeoJSON/blob/master/lib/threeGeoJSON.js

and `USA.geo.json` from here:
https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries/USA.geo.json

I tried 3 approaches and they all failed ..

## 1 - same as Marcs answer

```
function createVertexForEachPoint(object_geometry, values_axis1, values_axis2,values_axis3) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values_axis1.length; i++) {
        var v = new THREE.Vector3(
        values_axis1[i],
        values_axis2[i], 
        values_axis3[i]
        );
    object_geometry.vertices.push(v);
    if (i>=values_axis1.length-1) continue;
    object_geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, i + 1, i));
    }
}
```

and the result:

[image: test 1]

## 2 - using THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape

```
function createVertexForEachPoint(object_geometry, values_axis1, values_axis2,values_axis3) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values_axis1.length; i++) {
        var v = new THREE.Vector3(
        values_axis1[i],
        values_axis2[i], 
        values_axis3[i]
        );
    object_geometry.vertices.push(v);
    }
    var holes = [];
    var triangles = THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape ( object_geometry.vertices, holes );
    for( var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++ ){
        object_geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( triangles[i][0], triangles[i][1], triangles[i][2] ));
    }
}
```

and the result:

[image: test 2]

## 3 - using Earcut

https://github.com/mapbox/earcut

```
function createVertexForEachPoint(object_geometry, values_axis1, values_axis2,values_axis3) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values_axis1.length; i++) {
        var v = new THREE.Vector3(
        values_axis1[i],
        values_axis2[i], 
        values_axis3[i]
        );
    object_geometry.vertices.push(v);
    }
    var data = [];
    for(var i=0;i<object_geometry.vertices.length;i++) {
        data.push(object_geometry.vertices[i].x);
        data.push(object_geometry.vertices[i].y);
        data.push(object_geometry.vertices[i].z);
    }
    var triangles = earcut(data, null, 3);
    for( var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i+=3 ){
        object_geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( triangles[i], triangles[i+1], triangles[i+2] ));
    }
}
```

and the result:

[image: test 3]

The yellow lines are the outline of USA - And they are correct

The red is the faces that need to fill the yellow lines...

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520463/how-can-i-draw-geojson-in-three-js-as-a-mesh-and-not-a-line-and-fill-with-color#comment68326926_40538143) under the Marcs's answer?

Comment: Yes, And I tried to load israel geometry with no luck..